# The equation $y^2-x^t=k$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

S.E board!

This is a Diophantine equations problem, which is so interesting one can do by plugging the suitable values in unknown. When it comes for finding set of all solutions is may be tough. I would like to learn to find all solutions of this equations with the help of m.s.e.

> If $t \geq 3$  be prime and consider $y^2-x^t= k$ for some
>   fixed integer number $k$. This equation has a solution
>   in $Z_P$ for all $p$ if and only if it has one for primes $p$ of the
>   form $p = 2qt + 1$ with $1 \leqslant q  \leqslant  (t-3)/2$

Please prove the validity of the above cited statement!

Comment: Please make titles informative. It would be good if you provide the source of this problem. Is it from a book? An article? A problem set? You could also use a read from [this](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).